# Установка размера картинки на карточке bootstrap

Tags: java, css, bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Имеется такая карточка

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru_RU" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<th:block th:fragment="shop_item_list">
<div class="row">
    <div th:each="shop_item,stat: ${shopItems}" class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card mb-3">

            <div class="card-body">


                    <div class="shop_item_img">
                        <a th:href="'/item/'+${shop_item.id}">
                            <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel"
                                 id="carouselExampleInterval">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img alt="..." class="img-responsive"
                                             th:src="'data:image/png; Base64,' + ${convertor
                                            .imageInByteToBase64(shop_item.images[0].picture)}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="10000"
                                         th:each="img : ${shop_item.images}">
                                        <img alt="..." class="img-fluid d-block w-100"
                                             th:src="'data:image/png; Base64,' + ${convertor.imageInByteToBase64(img.picture)}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${shop_item.name}">Product Name</h5>
                <p class="card-text" th:text="${shop_item.description}">Material</p>
                <p class="card-text" th:text="${shop_item.price}">Price</p>




                <a th:href="@{/item/{itemid} (itemid=${shop_item.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Открыть</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</th:block>
</body>
</html>
```

Проблема в том, что картинка неадыкватного размера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать какздесь, чтобы все были одинаковые небольшие
Вот пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите

Подскажите где устанавливается размер содержимого карты или если ли возможность сделать все карты одного размера

Comment: Уберите классы `img-fluid` и `w-100`. Посмотрите что навешено на класс `img-responsive` и добавьте его во вторую карточку, возможно там все стили и заданы.

Comment: Изменил код вставки изображения

                        <div class="item_img">
                            <a th:href="'/item/'+${shop_item.id}">
                                <img alt="..." class="img-responsive" th:src="'data:image/png; Base64,'
                                + ${convertor.imageInByteToBase64(shop_item.images[0].picture)}">
                            </a>
                        </div>
Теперь картинка вставляется как в оригинале
Как ее уменьшить?